# FoxPro DBF и C#

Tags: c#, odbc, foxpro

Столкнулся с проблемой открытия файла .dbf созданным в VFP.
При попытке:

```
OdbcConnection con = new OdbcConnection("Driver={Microsoft Visual FoxPro Driver};SourceType=DBF;SourceDB=c://clndates.dbf;Exclusive=No");
con.Open();
```

Пишет:

> Additional information: ERROR [IM001] [Microsoft][Диспетчер драйверов ODBC] Драйвер не поддерживает данную функцию.

При подключении через Ole

```
_connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=vfpoledb;Data Source=C:\123\clndates.dbf;Collating Sequence=machine;Mode=ReadWrite;";
```

Ругается на
1. Отсутствие файлов .DBC
2. При добавлении недостающих файлов -  the provider could not determine the decimal value...

По сути, мне необходимо открывать одну таблицу и выгружать некоторые данные в .xml при изменении таблицы. Поэтому открывать всю БД смысла нет.
Наткнулся в интернете на программку под названием DBF Viewer 2000. Она спокойно открывает отдельные таблицы.

Каким образом еще можно открывать данный тип файлов?
И почему ODBC не поддерживает открытие файлов? (Понятно, что поддержка прекратилась, но открывать то должен).

Answer (score 0):

Нашел косяк.

Через OLE, если выбирать полностью все данные `Execute("SELECT * FROM " + dbpath);` то будет ошибка.

Если же `Execute("SELECT CLIENT, INDEX FROM " + dbpath);` то все работает.

Но все равно, хотелось бы понять, возможно ли отдельно открыть файлы dbf.